# Server always throws 403 on Angularjs ajax call in Django

Tags: angularjs, django, angularjs-service

Server always throws 403 in my Django app. I tried using csrf along with the data that is being posted to server, but still no luck. What am I missing ?

Here is how am invoking the `$http` service function

```
   <body ng-controller="rdCtrl">
        <a ng-click="saveprof()">Save</a>  

   <script>
    var app = angular.module('rdExampleApp', ['ui.rdplot']);
    app.controller('rdCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.dataset = {
     "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
     "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
     "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
     "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
     "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
      };

      $scope.func = function func() {
             var jdata = $scope.dataset;
             return jdata;
        }

        $scope.saveprof = function () {
            //show spinner        
            $('.spinner').show();
            $http.post('saveprof', {
                data: { 'data': $scope.dataset},
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            })
                      .success(function (data) {
                          if (data == "null") {
                              //your code if return data empty 
                          } else {
                              //your code if return data not empty 
                              $('#message').html(data);
                          }
                          //hide spinner
                          $('.spinner').fadeOut();
                      })
                      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          console.log('error' + status);
                          //hide spinner in case of error
                          $('.spinner').fadeOut();
                      })
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

I corrected it, ajax call is being invoked when I click on button - but it returns 403 error.. Access forbidden.. I have view saveprof in my django views.. and also I used csrf token.. Am not sure why server returns 403. (http:/x.x.x.x/saveprof)

What am I missing?

Comment: Try injecting `$http` into your controller.

Comment: The first parameter of $http.post needs to be a URL

Comment: 'saveprof' is the url alias.. it routes to some view in Django framework

Comment: Remove all your `$http` code from the `saveProf` functon, and just put a `console.log('here')` statement. Are you getting there from the `ngClick`? Your functions are defined strangely on `$scope`, almost as if you put closures around them. Just see if you can get the `saveProf` function to fire.

Comment: Also please stop using `.success` and `.error`. Use `.then` and `.catch` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inject $http to the controller as parameter

```
app.controller('rdCtrl', function ($scope, $http) { .. }
```

Comment: Hi Golois, Thanks a lot for this. I corrected it, however server always returns 403 error.. but the url is working when I directly use (http:/x.x.x.x/saveprof)... am suspecting this is related to Django framework, server throws error if csrf is not being used.. I tried using it along with data, but still it throws 403.. Can you help ?

Comment: Try to make a post request using a tool like fiddler or if you have chrome, try to add this app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US    This will help you test your API and to ensure that it's working correctly